# Djangoのformにview内でファイルをセットする方法

Tags: python, django

Djangoのformにて一度、tempディレクトリにアップロードしたファイルをViewの中で再度formにセットし、他のviewへ渡す、という動きを実現したいのですが、下記のようなコードで実装した場合、TypeErrorやobject does not support item assignmentといったエラーが発生していしまいます。

-forms.py

```
class SampleForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.Field(required=False,widget = forms.FileInput)
```

-views.py

```
def sample(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SampleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    file_upload(request.FILES['image'], アップロードディレクトリ)
    form['image'] = open(アップロードディレクトリ+ファイル名, 'rb')

    return render(request, リダイレクト先, {'form' : form})
```

何か良い方法があればご教示いただければと思います